# How to make <img> align to justify in a div?

Tags: css

```css
.avator {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="avator">
  <img src="1.png" />
  <img src="2.png" />
  <img src="3.png" />
  <img src="4.png" />
  <img src="5.png" />
</div>
```

why the `img` not justified?
the 5 imgs is in one or two lines according to the div's width.
it all align to left.

this is the image.

[image]

If I use @Temani Afif's img it is :

[image]

same code same css.why the display is not same?

Comment: You should use flex to align images as @ray answered, also you have to set the ratio to your images to display in right way and not too much stretched or squeeze

Answer (score 0):

You could use `display: flex` for this.

```css
.avator {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.avator > * {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="avator">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/64x64.png/666/fff/?text=A" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/64x64.png/666/fff/?text=B" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/64x64.png/666/fff/?text=C" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/64x64.png/666/fff/?text=D" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/64x64.png/666/fff/?text=E" />
</div>
```

Comment: but I just want to use text-align,can it do?

Comment: If there is many img it can not change to next line but no space between imgs

Answer (score 0):

It works almost the same way as text, so if you want to justify the last row you will need some hack:

```css
.avator {
  text-align: justify;
}
.avator:after {
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="avator">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/10/100/100.jpg" >
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/10/100/100.jpg" >
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/10/100/100.jpg" >
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/10/100/100.jpg" >
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/10/100/100.jpg" >
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/10/100/100.jpg" >
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/10/100/100.jpg" >
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/10/100/100.jpg" >
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/10/100/100.jpg" >
</div>
```

Comment: my code is same to yours but not work.I can not understand why

Comment: @newprogrammer show your full code here: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I find the problem. it is the <img > code.If I copy your imgs to mine .then is ok.

Comment: <img src="../../image/user2.png"> is not ok.and   <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/10/100/100.jpg" > is ok.

Comment: @newprogrammer well, I don't know what kind of image you are using. Can you share a screenshot of the result?

Comment: plese check it . in the question.

Comment: @newprogrammer can you share a link to your website or something so I can see the result with your images and inspect the code?

Comment: @newprogrammer wait, you are using 7 image which give you only one image at the last row so it will stay at the left which is logical

Comment: no .I can not open jsfiddle.net. so I can not upload the code.

Comment: I do not understand